# Reject http requests handled by endpoints that don't specify security restrictions

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm trying to protect against accidentally publishing an endpoint with no security in place. @Secured, @PreAuthorize, @PostAuthorize, etc.

I would want requests made to endpoints that don't specify any security requirements to be automatically rejected (403 Forbidden)

If an endpoint should indeed be open to the public it would need to be tagged by an annotation or similar.

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/endpoint1")
    public void accidentallyOpen() {
    }

    @GetMapping("/endpoint2")
    @UnrestrictedEndpoint
    public void intentionallyOpen() {
    }
}
```

In the above example I'm expecting

- Requests made to /endpoint1 should return 403 Forbidden.
- Requests made to /endpoint2 should return 204 No Content

I'm not sure where to start. Also if there are better ways of doing this I'm also happy to learn.